# Is pthread FIFO scheduling not strictly deterministic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, pthreads, rhel

I'm trying to get this thread to always be running on one CPU core (out of 24) whenever the process it's in is running:

```
void *t_mon_func(void *)
{
  while (true) {
    if (f) {
      break_on();
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

I configure it for SCHED_FIFO scheduling and maximum priority.  I have 50 other threads running (with default priority) with this thread function:

```
void *tfunc(void *)
{
  std::atomic<unsigned> i = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (f) {
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

In gdb, I set a breakpoint on the `break_on` function, continue the program, which then is triggered to change the value of `f` (a global variable) to a non-zero value (via a system call from a lower priority thread).  When the breakpoint is hit, the value of `i` in many of the low-priority threads is in the thousands or tens of thousands.  This seems to indicate that the real-time, high-priorty thread is somehow not always running (while the process is running).  Or am I missing something?  The full progam is in x.cc here:  https://github.com/ywkaras/MiscRepo/tree/master/TWATCH .  (I run the program as root.)

Comment: high-priorty != realtime != always running

Comment: bare assertion != useful

Comment: I don't think your test tests what you think it tests since it's based on starting and stopping things, not things running in a steady-state condition. The platform may well start and stop things in some particular order that leaves some things running and other things not running at various points in the process.

Comment: @WaltK I think the problem is that your own statement `"...the real-time, high-priorty thread is somehow not always running..."` appears to equate the notions of high-priorty and realtime.  There are any number of reasons for an OS kernel to swap threads in and out.  You appear to assume that setting the atomic int `f` to a no-zero value will act as a signal to swap in the high priority thread -- that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping someone knows more specifically than "any number of reasons".  In realtime OSes with deterministic scheduling, a runnable thread that has higher priority than any other thread is always running unless there are ISRs running on all of the cores I think.  I don't see why the high priority thread in my program would ever not be runnable, it does no system calls.

Answer (score 4):

> This seems to indicate that the real-time, high-priorty thread is somehow not always running

Your conclusion does not follow from observed facts.

On Linix, when a breakpoint is hit in the `SCHED_FIFO` thread, that thread is no longer runnable, but all the other threads are, and so continue to run. (Note: other OSes stop all threads when any thread hits a breakpoint, but Linux doesn't.)

Since the FIFO thread is being debugged, the kernel (eventually) notifies GDB (via `waitpid` return) that this thread has stopped (other threads continue running).

When GDB notices that the FIFO thread has stopped, it then stops all other threads (only in `all-stop` mode), and finally gives the prompt back. It is only at that moment that you can examine the value of `i` in all threads.

While the time between GDB waking up and stopping all threads is pretty short (usually milliseconds), it should not be surprising that other threads managed to increment a variable 10s of thousands of time.

---

Comment: Hmm but when I add ```show non-stop``` to the gdb script the output is ```Controlling the inferior in non-stop mode is off.```

Comment: @WaltK `non-stop mode is off` is equivalent to `all-stop mode`. So nothing new? In non-stop mode, the other threads will keep on running, incrementing `i` even more.

Comment: So does the x86 architecture lack the capability of configuring an execution breakpoint that halts all cores and only allows a single core to execute the associated ISR?

Comment: @WaltK I don't know, but you are mixing completely unrelated things. There are no `ISR`s anywhere near user-space (which is where your program runs).

Comment: @ Employed Russian I think breakpoints cause a switch to kernel context at least for the core that hit the breakpoint (and entry into an ISR).

Comment: It's not a hardware issue, @WaltK, unless by "halt all cores" you mean "hang the computer".  Yours is a *scheduling* issue.  You want all threads belonging to a particular process to instantaneously become ineligible to run, but that cannot happen on a multicore system because it is the operating system that manages scheduling, not the the CPU(s), and even under the most favorable circumstances, the OS must expend some effort to identify the threads that must no longer run and mark them ineligible. Plus whatever time it takes for them to actually stop.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, yes, pthread FIFO scheduling is deterministic.  I made two assumptions in asking this question, one or both of which are wrong:

1. The x86_64 architecture allows for setting an execution breakpoint that causes one core to jump to an ISR, and all the other cores to suspend execution.
2. GDB for x86_64 uses such a capability for execution breakpoints.

I changed the function for the low-priority threads to:

```
void *tfunc(void *)
{
  std::atomic<unsigned> i = 0;

  while (!flag) {
    ;
  }
  while (run) {
    ++i;
  }

  if (i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }

  return nullptr;
}
```

And the function for the high-priority thread to:

```
void *t_mon_func(void *)
{
  while (!flag) {
    ;
  }
  run = 0;
  flag = 0;

  return nullptr;
}
```

(The revised program is in x.cc in https://github.com/ywkaras/MiscRepo/tree/master/TWATCH2 .)

The largest output value for `i` in any low-priority thread was 13.

One thing is I still don't understand is that, if I increase the number of low-priority threads to much more than 10, the program will never exit.

(I attempted to delete the question but I got a response saying that it's best not to delete questions with answers.)